# jquery UI theme issue (text not visible)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themeroller

Jquery UI theme.css has

```
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
        border: 1px solid #45930b;
        background: #4ca20b url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_60_4ca20b_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #ffffff;
}
```

For textArea with more than 10 rows, the background image can not cover the whole textArea, and as a result some text(color: #ffffff) have the same color with background and become not visible.

If I change repeat-x to repeat, the background does not look good. Any simple fix?
Thanks.